# Prove that for every real number 'a' lim f(x) as x approaches 'a' does not exist.

Tags: calculus

I am a beginner in calculus, I guess this problem can somehow be proved using sandwich theorem but I have no idea on how to approach this problem.

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\mathbb Q\\-1&x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
>   Prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist for any real $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What can you say about the numbers that appear in an open interval around any rational number? Around any irrational number?

Comment: I researched on the internet about neighbourhood of a rational and irrational. In an open interval, if there is a rational number/irrational number then around it there exist infinitely many rational and irrational numbers and vice versa

Comment: How to use this to prove the given problem?

Comment: That's the right approach. Now, to prove that it is discontinuous at any rational number, choose any $\epsilon<2$. Can you show that no $\delta>0$ works?

Comment: I am assuming that is epsilon-delta definition for limits which I have not learned. Is there any way other than this, if not can you link me to a source where I can learn this? I tried searching and watching a few videos but it all went over my head.

Comment: |x-a| < delta -> 0 < epsilon but epsilon is positive so that means limit does not exist for rational numbers, am I right? If yes, how to approach for irrational numbers?

Comment: This is wrong and I am back to zero

Answer (score 1):

To prove discontinuity at $a$, find a sequence $a_n$ satisfying $a_n\to a,\,f(a_n)\not\to f(a)$. For $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, choose $a_n=a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n+1}$ so $f(a_n)=-1\ne 1=f(a)$. For $a\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, choose a sequence of rational $a_n$ (e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents)) so $f(a_n)=1\ne -1=f(a)$.

Comment: Haven't learned Sequential characterization either. Can you explain or link me to somewhere I can learn this from start?

Comment: @DiagaAoS I'd never heard that term for it, but it makes perfect sense. The continuity of $f$ at $a$ has several equivalent conditions, including the one I've used; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences). I recommend reading through all its definitions, then convincing yourself they're equivalent (or looking up proofs).

Comment: @ J.G. Why did you choose a_n=a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n+1} ?

Comment: @DiagaAoS it's an easy way to get a sequence of irrational numbers. The $+1$ is in case your indices start at $0$.

Comment: Can you tell if I am thinking correctly? The sequence I mentioned in the comments, if a is rational then, that sequence consists of all irrational numbers where n is starting from zero and converge back to a which is rational. That is why f(a_n) is irrational and equal to -1 and f(a) is rational and equal to 1 @J.G.

Comment: And I learnt a sequence of rational numbers i.e (1+1/n)^n which converges to e which is an irrational number, now by definition, I can prove discontinuity. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @DiagaAoS That strategy would prove discontinuity at $e$. I linked to a discussion of convergence that will work for any irrational.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84134/discussion-between-diaga-aos-and-j-g).

Answer (score 0):

I understand this problem. Thank you for help.
[image: Answer]